Error (suppressible): (vsim-3584) Module parameter 'ARGVALUE0' not found for override
I'm trying to simulate Core1553BRT_APB LiberoSoc IP Core via user testbench provided by this Core. When I launch RTL simulation (I'm using ModelSim Microsemi Pro 2020.4), it gives me Error (suppressible): (vsim-3584). Below I attach the full log:
# Reading pref.tcl
# do run.do
# INFO: Simulation library presynth already exists
# Model Technology ModelSim Microsemi Pro vmap 2020.4 Lib Mapping Utility 2020.10 Oct 14 2020
# vmap presynth presynth 
# Modifying modelsim.ini
# Model Technology ModelSim Microsemi Pro vmap 2020.4 Lib Mapping Utility 2020.10 Oct 14 2020
# vmap PolarFire C:/Microsemi/Libero_SoC_v2021.2/Designer/lib/modelsimpro/precompiled/vlog/PolarFire 
# Modifying modelsim.ini
# Model Technology ModelSim Microsemi Pro vmap 2020.4 Lib Mapping Utility 2020.10 Oct 14 2020
# vmap CORE1553BRT_APB_LIB ../component/Actel/DirectCore/CORE1553BRT_APB/4.4.100/mti/lib_vlog_eval/CORE1553BRT_APB_LIB 
# Modifying modelsim.ini
# Model Technology ModelSim Microsemi Pro vcom 2020.4 Compiler 2020.10 Oct 14 2020
# Start time: 18:06:59 on Aug 30,2024
# vcom -reportprogress 300 -work CORE1553BRT_APB_LIB -force_refresh 
# -- Skipping module BFM_1553BBC
# -- Skipping module BFM_APB
# -- Skipping module BFM_MAIN
# -- Skipping module BFMA1l1OII
# -- Skipping module BRT_BACKEND
# -- Skipping module BRT_CWLEGALITY
# -- Skipping module BRT_DECODER
# -- Skipping module BRT_ENCODER
# -- Skipping module BRT_RT1553B
# -- Skipping module CORE1553BRT_APB_C0_CORE1553BRT_APB_C0_0_CORE1553BRT_APB
# -- Skipping module TB_AMBA
# End time: 18:07:00 on Aug 30,2024, Elapsed time: 0:00:01
# Errors: 0, Warnings: 0
# Model Technology ModelSim Microsemi Pro vlog 2020.4 Compiler 2020.10 Oct 14 2020
# Start time: 18:07:00 on Aug 30,2024
# vlog -reportprogress 300 -work CORE1553BRT_APB_LIB -force_refresh 
# -- Refreshing module BFM_1553BBC
# -- Refreshing module BFM_APB
# -- Refreshing module BFM_MAIN
# -- Refreshing module BFMA1l1OII
# -- Refreshing module BRT_BACKEND
# -- Refreshing module BRT_CWLEGALITY
# -- Refreshing module BRT_DECODER
# -- Refreshing module BRT_ENCODER
# -- Refreshing module BRT_RT1553B
# -- Refreshing module CORE1553BRT_APB_C0_CORE1553BRT_APB_C0_0_CORE1553BRT_APB
# -- Refreshing module TB_AMBA
# End time: 18:07:00 on Aug 30,2024, Elapsed time: 0:00:00
# Errors: 0, Warnings: 0
# Model Technology ModelSim Microsemi Pro vlog 2020.4 Compiler 2020.10 Oct 14 2020
# Start time: 18:07:00 on Aug 30,2024
# vlog -reportprogress 300 -sv -work CORE1553BRT_APB_LIB D:/Work_Projects/LiberoSoc/UserTestbanch_1553BRT/component/work/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0_0/rtl/verilog/amba_eval/core1553brt_apb.v 
# -- Compiling module CORE1553BRT_APB_C0_CORE1553BRT_APB_C0_0_CORE1553BRT_APB
# 
# Top level modules:
#   CORE1553BRT_APB_C0_CORE1553BRT_APB_C0_0_CORE1553BRT_APB
# End time: 18:07:00 on Aug 30,2024, Elapsed time: 0:00:00
# Errors: 0, Warnings: 0
# Model Technology ModelSim Microsemi Pro vlog 2020.4 Compiler 2020.10 Oct 14 2020
# Start time: 18:07:00 on Aug 30,2024
# vlog -reportprogress 300 -sv -work presynth D:/Work_Projects/LiberoSoc/UserTestbanch_1553BRT/component/work/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0.v 
# -- Compiling module CORE1553BRT_APB_C0
# 
# Top level modules:
#   CORE1553BRT_APB_C0
# End time: 18:07:00 on Aug 30,2024, Elapsed time: 0:00:00
# Errors: 0, Warnings: 0
# Model Technology ModelSim Microsemi Pro vlog 2020.4 Compiler 2020.10 Oct 14 2020
# Start time: 18:07:00 on Aug 30,2024
# vlog -reportprogress 300 "+incdir+D:/Work_Projects/LiberoSoc/UserTestbanch_1553BRT/component/Actel/DirectCore/CORE1553BRT_APB/4.4.100" "+incdir+D:/Work_Projects/LiberoSoc/UserTestbanch_1553BRT/component/work/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0_0/rtl/verilog/tb_amba_eval" -sv -work CORE1553BRT_APB_LIB D:/Work_Projects/LiberoSoc/UserTestbanch_1553BRT/component/work/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0_0/rtl/verilog/tb_amba_eval/tb_amba.v 
# -- Compiling module TB_AMBA
# 
# Top level modules:
#   TB_AMBA
# End time: 18:07:00 on Aug 30,2024, Elapsed time: 0:00:00
# Errors: 0, Warnings: 0
# vsim -L PolarFire -L presynth -L CORE1553BRT_APB_LIB -t 1ps -pli "C:/Microsemi/Libero_SoC_v2021.2/Designer/lib/modelsimpro/pli/pf_crypto_win_me_pli.dll" CORE1553BRT_APB_LIB.TB_AMBA 
# Start time: 18:07:00 on Aug 30,2024
# //  ModelSim Microsemi Pro 2020.4 Oct 14 2020
# //
# //  Copyright 1991-2020 Mentor Graphics Corporation
# //  All Rights Reserved.
# //
# //  ModelSim Microsemi Pro and its associated documentation contain trade
# //  secrets and commercial or financial information that are the property of
# //  Mentor Graphics Corporation and are privileged, confidential,
# //  and exempt from disclosure under the Freedom of Information Act,
# //  5 U.S.C. Section 552. Furthermore, this information
# //  is prohibited from disclosure under the Trade Secrets Act,
# //  18 U.S.C. Section 1905.
# //
# Loading sv_std.std
# Loading CORE1553BRT_APB_LIB.TB_AMBA
# Loading CORE1553BRT_APB_LIB.BFM_1553BBC
# Loading CORE1553BRT_APB_LIB.BRT_ENCODER
# Loading CORE1553BRT_APB_LIB.BRT_DECODER
# ** Error (suppressible): (vsim-3584) D:/Work_Projects/LiberoSoc/UserTestbanch_1553BRT/component/work/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0_0/rtl/verilog/tb_amba_eval/tb_amba.v(342): Module parameter 'ARGVALUE0' not found for override.
#    Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 0  Instance: /TB_AMBA File: D:/Work_Projects/LiberoSoc/UserTestbanch_1553BRT/component/work/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0_0/rtl/verilog/tb_amba_eval/tb_amba.v
# ** Error (suppressible): (vsim-3584) D:/Work_Projects/LiberoSoc/UserTestbanch_1553BRT/component/work/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0_0/rtl/verilog/tb_amba_eval/tb_amba.v(342): Module parameter 'ARGVALUE1' not found for override.
#    Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 0  Instance: /TB_AMBA File: D:/Work_Projects/LiberoSoc/UserTestbanch_1553BRT/component/work/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0_0/rtl/verilog/tb_amba_eval/tb_amba.v
# ** Error (suppressible): (vsim-3584) D:/Work_Projects/LiberoSoc/UserTestbanch_1553BRT/component/work/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0_0/rtl/verilog/tb_amba_eval/tb_amba.v(342): Module parameter 'ARGVALUE10' not found for override.
#    Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 0  Instance: /TB_AMBA File: D:/Work_Projects/LiberoSoc/UserTestbanch_1553BRT/component/work/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0_0/rtl/verilog/tb_amba_eval/tb_amba.v
# ** Error (suppressible): (vsim-3584) D:/Work_Projects/LiberoSoc/UserTestbanch_1553BRT/component/work/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0_0/rtl/verilog/tb_amba_eval/tb_amba.v(342): Module parameter 'ARGVALUE11' not found for override.
#    Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 0  Instance: /TB_AMBA File: D:/Work_Projects/LiberoSoc/UserTestbanch_1553BRT/component/work/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0_0/rtl/verilog/tb_amba_eval/tb_amba.v
# ** Error (suppressible): (vsim-3584) D:/Work_Projects/LiberoSoc/UserTestbanch_1553BRT/component/work/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0_0/rtl/verilog/tb_amba_eval/tb_amba.v(342): Module parameter 'ARGVALUE2' not found for override.
#    Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 0  Instance: /TB_AMBA File: D:/Work_Projects/LiberoSoc/UserTestbanch_1553BRT/component/work/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0_0/rtl/verilog/tb_amba_eval/tb_amba.v
# ** Error (suppressible): (vsim-3584) D:/Work_Projects/LiberoSoc/UserTestbanch_1553BRT/component/work/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0_0/rtl/verilog/tb_amba_eval/tb_amba.v(342): Module parameter 'ARGVALUE3' not found for override.
#    Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 0  Instance: /TB_AMBA File: D:/Work_Projects/LiberoSoc/UserTestbanch_1553BRT/component/work/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0_0/rtl/verilog/tb_amba_eval/tb_amba.v
# ** Error (suppressible): (vsim-3584) D:/Work_Projects/LiberoSoc/UserTestbanch_1553BRT/component/work/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0_0/rtl/verilog/tb_amba_eval/tb_amba.v(342): Module parameter 'ARGVALUE4' not found for override.
#    Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 0  Instance: /TB_AMBA File: D:/Work_Projects/LiberoSoc/UserTestbanch_1553BRT/component/work/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0_0/rtl/verilog/tb_amba_eval/tb_amba.v
# ** Error (suppressible): (vsim-3584) D:/Work_Projects/LiberoSoc/UserTestbanch_1553BRT/component/work/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0_0/rtl/verilog/tb_amba_eval/tb_amba.v(342): Module parameter 'ARGVALUE5' not found for override.
#    Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 0  Instance: /TB_AMBA File: D:/Work_Projects/LiberoSoc/UserTestbanch_1553BRT/component/work/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0_0/rtl/verilog/tb_amba_eval/tb_amba.v
# ** Error (suppressible): (vsim-3584) D:/Work_Projects/LiberoSoc/UserTestbanch_1553BRT/component/work/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0_0/rtl/verilog/tb_amba_eval/tb_amba.v(342): Module parameter 'ARGVALUE6' not found for override.
#    Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 0  Instance: /TB_AMBA File: D:/Work_Projects/LiberoSoc/UserTestbanch_1553BRT/component/work/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0_0/rtl/verilog/tb_amba_eval/tb_amba.v
# ** Error (suppressible): (vsim-3584) D:/Work_Projects/LiberoSoc/UserTestbanch_1553BRT/component/work/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0_0/rtl/verilog/tb_amba_eval/tb_amba.v(342): Module parameter 'ARGVALUE7' not found for override.
#    Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 0  Instance: /TB_AMBA File: D:/Work_Projects/LiberoSoc/UserTestbanch_1553BRT/component/work/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0_0/rtl/verilog/tb_amba_eval/tb_amba.v
# ** Error (suppressible): (vsim-3584) D:/Work_Projects/LiberoSoc/UserTestbanch_1553BRT/component/work/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0_0/rtl/verilog/tb_amba_eval/tb_amba.v(342): Module parameter 'ARGVALUE8' not found for override.
#    Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 0  Instance: /TB_AMBA File: D:/Work_Projects/LiberoSoc/UserTestbanch_1553BRT/component/work/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0_0/rtl/verilog/tb_amba_eval/tb_amba.v
# ** Error (suppressible): (vsim-3584) D:/Work_Projects/LiberoSoc/UserTestbanch_1553BRT/component/work/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0_0/rtl/verilog/tb_amba_eval/tb_amba.v(342): Module parameter 'ARGVALUE9' not found for override.
#    Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 0  Instance: /TB_AMBA File: D:/Work_Projects/LiberoSoc/UserTestbanch_1553BRT/component/work/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0/CORE1553BRT_APB_C0_0/rtl/verilog/tb_amba_eval/tb_amba.v
# Error loading design
# Error: Error loading design
#        Pausing macro execution
# MACRO ./run.do PAUSED at line 21

As I understand, ARGVALUE0-11 are parameters belonging to module BFM_APB (below is a fragment of the testbench code where ARGVALUE0-11 are mentioned):
BFM_APB #( .VECTFILE        ( "core1553brt.vec"),
               .MAX_INSTRUCTIONS( 8192),
               .MAX_STACK       ( 200),
               .TPD             ( 5),
               .DEBUGLEVEL      ( -1),
               .ARGVALUE0       ( VERIF),          
               .ARGVALUE1       ( NRTS),       
               .ARGVALUE2       ( FAMILY),       
               .ARGVALUE3       ( SU_CLKSPD),       
               .ARGVALUE4       ( SU_CLKSYNC),      
               .ARGVALUE5       ( SU_LOCKRT),       
               .ARGVALUE6       ( BCASTEN),      
               .ARGVALUE7       ( SU_LEGMODE),      
               .ARGVALUE8       ( SA30LOOP),     
               .ARGVALUE9       ( INTENBBR),    
               .ARGVALUE10      ( SU_TESTTXTOUTEN),
               .ARGVALUE11      ( SU_INT_POLARITY)
    ) BFM(
        .SYSCLK(SYSCLK), 
        .SYSRSTN(SYSRSTN), 
        .PCLK(PCLK), 
        .PRESETN(PRESETN), 
        .PADDR(PADDR), 
        .PENABLE(PENABLE), 
        .PWRITE(PWRITE), 
        .PWDATA(PWDATA), 
        .PRDATA(PRDATA), 
        .PREADY(PREADY), 
        .PSLVERR(PSLVERR), 
        .PSEL(PSEL), 
        .INTERRUPT(INTERRUPT), 
        .GP_OUT(GP_OUT), 
        .GP_IN(GP_IN), 
        .EXT_WR(EXT_WR), 
        .EXT_RD(EXT_RD), 
        .EXT_ADDR(EXT_ADDR), 
        .EXT_DATA(EXT_DATA), 
        .EXT_WAIT(EXT_WAIT), 
        .FINISHED(FINISHED), 
        .FAILED(FAILED)
    ); 

But I don“t know how to fix this error, bc module BFM_APB is not available for viewing and modification:

Has anyone encountered a similar problem? What's the way to fix these errors?
I would appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance.

Finally, I managed to run this testbench. Initially, I tried to run it on PolarFire family in LiberoSoc v.2021.2:

And I didn't succeed because of the error described in my question.
Then, I tried to run it on other families and I succeeded on IGLOO2 and SmartFusion2. Below is a screenshot of waveforms obtained as a result of running the testbench:

